# How to watch content from a subfolder of a parent folder using watchman?

Tags: watchman

I am developing an image uploader by watching files. The images are enclosed in a folder (subfolder) and that folder is being copied in a parent folder that is being watched.

Example:

```
~/parent/subfolder1/image1.png
~/parent/subfolder2/image2.png
```

How do I watch these images using the parent folder argument being passed to watchman? or How do I include subfolders?

This is what I have now:

```
export PARENT_FOLDER = ~/parent/
export UPLOADER_SCRIPT = ~/upload_image.sh
watchman -- trigger $PARENT_FOLDER upload_image -- $UPLOADER_SCRIPT
```

Inside the `upload_image.sh` is just an upload function with the image file path as argument

```
python upload.py image1.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extended syntax: http://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/trigger#extended-syntax so that you can define richer matching expressions.  For example, this will match any `.png` file using a glob expression, but you can use any of the expression terms to scope this exactly how you need it:

```sh
$ watchman -j <<-EOT
["trigger", "/path/to/parent", {
  "name": "upload_image",
  "expression": ["match", "**/*.png"],
  "command": ["/path/to/upload_image.sh"]
}]
EOT
```

You may also want to take a look at [anyof](http://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/anyof) as a way to combine multiple criteria.

Comment: Thanks! How do you save this configuration in a .json? And call the json?

Comment: I think this answered my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291142/is-it-possible-to-configure-watchman-triggers-in-watchmanconfig